# js.erb View File Not Found

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the concept for dynamic select menus provided here:

http://samuelmullen.com/2011/02/dynamic-dropdowns-with-rails-jquery-and-ajax/

I've isolated my problem to the first parameter for .post in this code:

```
  this.change(function() {
    $.post("dvbd", that.val(), null, "script");
  });
```

I expect for the dvbd.js.erb file in the parent directory to be found and the jQuery contents therein executed. So, the location would be:

```
http://localhost:3000/parentdir/dvbd.js.erb
```

Instead, I get a 404 error where the location "`http://localhost:3000/parentdir/dvbd` is not found." So I don't even make it to the point to check if the javascript is actually being executed because the file where it resides is never found. However, I'm pretty sure it works because putting the same code in the local file results in successful execution of putting "Hello" in the Dave div:

```
$("#dave").html('Hello');
```

I can't really put the code in the local file because this isn't the code I'm actually trying to run. But since this fails first, it has to be solved first.

Comment: Do you have a route and a controller for handling dvdb.js.erb?

Comment: I'm missing the route. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The location will not be as described. The location will be:

```
http://localhost:3000/parentdir/dvbd
```

And in your controler (parentdir) and method dvbd you need to add:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
```

Anyway - the problem is that you did not define the method dvdb in your controller

Comment: It's actually already in the controller, so that's not it. But thanks for the suggestions.